# Combine two columns in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following df. For most of the rows, I have one missing value, but sometimes I don't.

```
name1 name2
carl  NaN
Nan   carl
peter Nan
NaN   peter
julia NaN
NaN   julia
jenny jenny
paul  paul
...
```

I want to combine these two columns and create a new column `name3`

so the desired df

```
name1 name2 name3
carl  NaN   carl
Nan   carl  carl
peter Nan   peter
NaN   peter peter
julia NaN   julia
NaN   julia julia
jenny jenny jenny
paul  paul  paul
...
```

Comment: `df['name3'] = df.bfill(axis=1)['name1']`

Comment: why only name1?

Comment: Give it a try, because `bfill` fills the data to the left

Comment: but I have many other columns..

Comment: Then slice the two before `bfill`